# Formatting plot with colour

Tags: r, plot

I have a question related to how I can format my plot so that the colour varies. My 3D plot is:

[image]

I would like it that at the higher points of the plot, the shade of blue is darker and then gradually going through to lighter shades of blue at the base.

Note that this was made using the persp() function and ideally I would rather not change this if at all possible.

Thanks!!

Comment: In the future, consider posting a reproducible example (see top R questoins on SO for tips on how to do that) and explain what you've tried and where/what doesn't work. We prefer solving coding problems, for everything professional consultants may be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help page for `persp` (`?persp`) and scroll to the bottom, the 4th example starts with this comment:

> # (4) Surface colours corresponding to z-values

Which is my interpretation of what you are asking.  Run that example and see if it does what you want (in general).  You will need to modify the function that generates the colors in order to see the colors that you specify (see the `colorRamp` function for one possibility) and modify it to use your data, but following that example should teach you the steps that you need.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was after thank you @Greg Snow ! Should probably read more of the help section in future!